# Django redirect 301 for www Subdomain

Tags: python, django, .htaccess, redirect, mod-wsgi

I have my Django app on hosting with Apache and mod_wsgi. It worked fine until I wanted to create a 301 redirect from no "www" to the "www". I changed **.htaccess**:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Now it's always redirect from **www.example.com** to:

```
http://www.example.com/index.wsgi/index.wsgi/
```

And I get a Page not found error. What did I do wrong? How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you using redirect within one domain,
you can get something like infinite loop.

For example, for example, first time your request will works fine. 
But after redirect RewriteCond will check again is current host == your host.
It's true, so to your request will add all, that you receive in previous request.

To prevent this, you can use something like below:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L,E=FINISH:1]
```

The first two lines help you to prevent infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this don't work. Is there a way to cancel redirect as if I never edit .htaccess?

Comment: what exactly doens't work? is this rule not redirects you?

Comment: It's always redirect from example.com and www.example.com to www.example.com/index.wsgi/index.wsgi/

Comment: do you have other .htaccess there?

Comment: Yes, one in the main folder and other in my django app folder.

Comment: So, first. have you edited your .htaccess with my rewriteRules attentively? Have you added E=FINISH:1 flag to the RewriteRule where redirect is?